# Get suggestive result for many to many relation

Tags: database, many-to-many, relational-database

I have a many to many table like

```
table tagged ( tid , pid ) 
// its a table to record all product that tagged with.
```

And i have a filter field which will accept many tag and then suggest a next **list of possible tag**.

The deal goes like ...

```
when the user filter with tid (1)
The query will search all product tagged with tid 1
then also get others tid that also tagged in returned result
Then group all related tags and order it descendingly
```

This is what i'm trying to do , but i'm lost. I have look and tried **Relational Division** but i think what i'm trying is way more complicate.

The sample is based on SQL fiddle provided.

**sample 1**

```
Input = tid 1

Desired output 
return list of suggestion In descending which are tid -> 
2 (total amount 7) ,
5 (total amount 4) ,
4 (total amount 3) ,
3 (total amount 1)
```

**sample 2**

```
Input = tid 1,2

Desired output 
return list of suggestion In descending which are tid -> 
5 (total amount 3) ,
4 (total amount 1) ,
3 (total amount 1)
```

Here is what i have now its only return all matched product [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f861)

Comment: I also wish to know the term i should go for...

Comment: Add some sample data please and desired result

Comment: @gbn updated my question , its follow the table in SQL fiddle

Comment: Solved with nested select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug into wrong path , what i actually need to use is a **nested select**.

**Solution**

```
SELECT count(tid) FROM tagged 

WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM tagged where tid = 1) AND tid != 1

GROUP BY tid
```

**Explanation**

1st

```
SELECT pid FROM tagged where tid = 1 //will return full list of product tagged with 1
```

2rd

```
SELECT count(tid) FROM tagged WHERE pid IN (1st)
AND tid != 1
//get all tid with return product in 1st query exclude selected tag
GROUP BY tid
//group it so i can sort it
```

Hope its help others. [Solution : nested select](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f861/26)